# What is the difference between an appx application and an appxbundle application?

Tags: windows-phone

I am new to Windows Phone development and have a quick question, it may be very simple to answer but I have had no luck whens searching.

What is the difference between an appx application and an appxbundle application?

Answer (score 5):

Single appx app targets specific architecture, appxbundle contains all architecture support mentioned while creating package.